# Is it OK to edit another person's answer to make it correct if they give you the answer through another means.

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked a question and someone posted an answer that was incorrect (off topic.)  However, in the comments of my question (not his answer) he gave me the correct answer.  I asked him to add the correct answer to his first answer, but he never did.  Is it OK for me to edit his answer, make it correct, and mark his answers with the check?

Comment: If it would totally change the answer - No. Post your own answer (giving attribution) and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not change the meaning of an answer.
Since you asked him to change his answer, and he has never done so, you can write your own answer basing on what he said in a comment. It is normally thought preferable to make the answer a Community Wiki, but I guess that depends also from how much of your own work you are adding to the answer somebody else suggested.